# How can I grant AWS users to access website hosted by s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am putting a website hosted by s3 bucket and I disabled public access. But this will block people to view the website via its `website endpoint`. I'd like to allow people who logged in AWS console to have access to this website. Is there a way for me to set it up in the s3 bucket?

Comment: Who are the "people who logged in AWS console"? Are you referring to only people in your own organisation (in your AWS Account), or are you referring to anybody in the world who are logged into an AWS Account (including other AWS Accounts)?

Comment: The people who is in my organisation.

Comment: The issue then becomes: How can the system identify the users logged into the console when they access your website. The answer is that it can't -- the AWS Console login is totally separate to how people access your website. You could make the website only accessible from a corporate network (if there is a network link between AWS and the corporate network), or users could access the Amazon S3 bucket via the AWS management console. Otherwise, you'll need to implement some form of login authentication for the website, which isn't easy for a static website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to set it up in the s3 bucket?

Sadly, if you want to use `website endpoint` then there is no straight forward way to do this. As explained in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html), a `website endpoint`:

> supports only **publicly readable content**

You can obviously limit access to your website endpoint through restricting IP addresses, but this is not for IAM users/roles. The point is the bucket must be public and accessible over the internet in general.

To restring your bucket content to IAM users/roles only, you need to use regular REST **API S3 endpoint** as it:

> supports both public and private content